# Dada una matriz de enteros, encuentra el par de elementos adyacentes que tiene el producto más grande y devuelve ese producto

Tags: javascript, codificación

**El problema radica en que no funciona con numeros negativos como en el siguiente ejemplo, alguien podra ayudarme para saber cual es mi error. eh provado con -infinite pero no me funciona o tal vez lo use mal. GRACIAS!!!**

```js
function solution(inputArray) {
  var mult1 = 0;
  var mult2 = 0;
  var max = 0;
  var ult = 0;
    
  for(i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
    mult2 = mult1;
    mult1 = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1];
    if(mult1 > mult2){
      max = mult1;
      if(max > ult){
        ult = max;
      }else{
        ult = ult;
      };
    }else{
      max = mult2;
      if(max > ult){
        ult = max;
      }else{
        ult = ult;
      };
    };
  };
  console.log(ult);
};

solution([-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás inicializando el valor de `max` a cero, por tanto, en un array donde todos los productos sean negativos no va a funcionar tu algoritmo. Lo mejor es inicializar tu variable al menor valor posible, en este caso, `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;`.

Por otro lado estás haciendo montón de comparaciones sin razón. Solo debes remplazar el valor de máximo si el producto actual es mayor al valor que tienes guardado. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
function solution(inputArray) {
    var max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length-1; i++) {
       if(inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1] > max){
           max = inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1];
       }
    }

    return max;
  };
  
  console.log(solution([-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]));
```

Alternativamente puedes guardar todos los productos en un arreglo y finalmente, devolver el máximo:

```js
function solution(inputArray) {
    var productos = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length-1; i++) {
        productos.push(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]);     
    }

    return Math.max(...productos);
  };

console.log(solution([-23, 4, -3, 8, -12]));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me abriste la prespectiva y tienes mucha razon.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que usar la propiedad map() es un poco más fácil de entender.

```
function solution(inputArray) {
   const product = inputArray.map(( num, index ) => {
     num = inputArray[index] * inputArray[index+1]
    return num
   })
   product.pop()
   return Math.max(...product)
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).